# how to access axios using react

Tags: reactjs, object, axios, state

im creating a quote generator using react. i'm having trouble accessing the object inside the arrays. viewing all the arrays is fine but when i try to specify which key i need, it says cannot read the property undefined

```
class Quote extends React.Component{
   state = {
       quotes : []

   }


componentDidMount(){
axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json').then(res=>{
this.setState({
    quotes: res.data.quotes
    })
})
}
render(){
    console.log(this.state.quotes[0])
```

this is the code that is working and it shows a result like this:

```
   {quote: "Life isn’t about getting and having, it’s about giving and being.", author: "Kevin Kruse"}
```

but when i use this instead:

```
   console.log(this.state.quotes[0].quote)
```

the error says :

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'quote' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is render isn't available initially and is loaded asynchronously post the initial render. You either need to use a loading state or conditionally access the state

```
class Quote extends React.Component{
   state = {
       quotes : []
       isLoading: true,
   }


componentDidMount(){

    axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json').then(res=>{
        this.setState({
            quotes: res.data.quotes,
            isLoading: false,
            })
        })

}
render(){
    if(this.state.isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>

    console.log(this.state.quotes[0])
```

Comment: thank you sir it works its just that isLoading needs to be false to render something thanks